# how to search multiple words in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I am not able to search values when I input queries like "word 1, word2" in the search box. My problem is that it does not display anything.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" value=" Search " />
</form>
<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$q=explode(',',$_POST['q']);
$q1=$q[0];
$q2=$q[1];
$q3=$q[2];
$q=mysql_escape_string($q);
$q_fix=str_replace(" ","%",$q); // Space replacing with %
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT title FROM articles WHERE title LIKE N'%$q_fix%'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
//$title=$row['title'];
//echo '<div>'.$title.'</div>';
echo $row['title'].'<br/>';
}

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `LIKE N'%$q_fix%'` what's that `N` doing in there? *ah, it's a typo I'll bet*

Comment: [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) is rarely [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); use something more appropriate, such as a paragraph or [list](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists) element, or apply styling to existing elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only an input named `q`:

```
<input type="text" name="q" />
```

Therefore the following will accessing the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) key-value array by then call [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

```
<?php 
$delimiter = ',';    

// validations, set value if exists otherwise null for evaluation 
$q = isset($_POST['q']) ? $_POST['q'] : null;

// null or check for empty string for early termination
if(!$q) {
  // TODO: handle error
  die();
}

// not null, assuming it is comma separated, validations done after  
$q = explode($delimiter, $q);

// validations ie. explode() returns FALSE, [] or [ .., .. ] so:
if(!$q or !is_array($q) or count($q) <= 0) {
  // TODO: handle error
  die();
} 

// some examples to prevent sql injection, xss, 
// omitting implementation of sanitize()
// refer to docs for purpose of each for different security preventions
// mysql_escape_string(), html_entities(), stripslashes(), trim();

$sanitised_array = sanitise($q);

// build query string while sanitizing inputs
// *Note: that LIKE is probably best avoided in this case for
// performance reasons given 'n' inputs ( although we know 'n' is small in this context ). 
// references are below, use IN ( slightly better ) instead

$sql_string = "SELECT title FROM articles WHERE title IN ($sanitised_array)";

// execute query
$result = mysql_query($sql_string);
if (!$result) {
  die('ERROR[BAD]: ' . mysql_error());
}

// mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array,
// a numeric array, or both

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  // validations
  if($row == null or !isset($row['title'])) {
    // TODO: log error  
    continue;
  }

  // *htmlentities()
  echo $row['title'].'<br/>';
}


?>
```

## References:

1. [MySQL IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)
2. [Why we do validations and sanitise user inputs](http://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/)
3. [PHP Data Filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)
4. [Database optimisations for LIKE, IN etc in another post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16284/how-expensive-are-select-from-like-statements-from-a-design-perspective)
5. [Article for further DB readings](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2616674/database-administration/10-essential-performance-tips-for-mysql.html)
6. [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - note the deprecation notice, use mysqli_query() instead

Hope this helps.

Comment: i understand but i'm in doubt where do i use my sql query inside the foreach ?????

Comment: ahh, ok ill whip up quickly. assuming that  you have 'n' inputs

Comment: @AnupSinghRana updated with stub and references. Hope this helps.

Comment: showing "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\search\index.php on line 63"   i've added after sql_string below code         "while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_string))
{
echo $row['title'].'<br/>';
}"

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($sql_string) takes in a resource $result ( of query ). you need to execute the query using mysql_query( );  i'll add a small snippet. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @AnupSinghRana, good lucks and hope you refer to the references listed moving forward. they do help and have fun!

Comment: @AnupSinghRana, Adrian Teh: Note that `die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling.

Comment: `mysqli` isn't simply a drop-in replacement for `mysql`; you should use different techniques afforded by it or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). Here, use prepared statements rather than interpolating values directly into the statement. Look into why `mysql` was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

With your query construct, not possible. With `LIKE` and multiple words that can be in any location, you have to split things up:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%word1%' AND LIKE '%word2%' AND ...
```

This sort of searching is highly inefficient - the DB cannot use indexes at all. You'd be better off using a [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index instead.

With your construct, `WHERE title LIKE '%foo bar%'`, you're requiring that the exact phrase `foo bar` be somewhere in the field. MySQL won't split that up look for `foo` and `bar` separately. So if your field contains `foo baz bar`, you won't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$sql="SELECT title FROM articles WHERE title";
foreach($q as $word) {
    if (!empty($word)) {
        $q_fix = str_replace(" ","%",$word);
        $sql .= " LIKE N'%{$word}%' OR";
    }
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, 'OR ');
print_r($sql);
```